# RStudio 1.0.143 error diagnostics

Tags: rstudio

since the last few days I am having a lot of issues when starting R-Studio 1.0.143. It often crashes at start up with "unfortunately R-Studio has stopped working" error followed by JavaScript Alert 127.0.0.0. 
I want to check the root cause by looking at Diagnostics available but not sure what I am looking at. Anyone how can point to how to improve R-Studio reliability? Just un-installed and installed again with nil help.

Comment: This is a print out from the diagnostics file.
`12 Jul 2017 12:20:15 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT: virtual void rstudio::core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest() C:/Users/Administrator/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:84; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const rstudio::core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:288`

Answer (score 0):

The only feasible solution was to revert back to Version 0.99.903. Nil problems since.